# GoDaddy, IIS, and Removing index.php

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, iis

I have Windows hosting through GoDaddy and setup WordPress with their Hosting for website.

Connection stuff. I am trying to get index.php removed from the URL for my pages but its not working. Whenever I add a web.config all I get is Error 500 pages.

Page: http://maxxlife.ca/index.php/supervisa-insurance/ (which I want to be just http://maxxlife.ca/supervisa-insurance)

I am under the impression that with the recommended web.config file and getting Error 500's with that means the Rewrite Module just isn't enabled. GoDaddy has basically told me that I need to enable it myself but I can't figure it out. Has anyone gotten this to work on Windows GoDaddy hosting?

Comment: check your permalink settings. Did you enter index.php in one of those fields?

Comment: Can we see your `web.config`?

Comment: thanks i have sort out this issue.